# Add http request in a ResponseEntity

Tags: java, http

I'm a beginner in web services and I want to add a http request in my ResponseEntity but I think I do it wrong.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/apiproxy", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity get(HttpServletRequest request, 
        @RequestParam("productName") String productName,
        @RequestParam("version") String version) {

    try {       
        String proxyName = productName.replaceFirst("_product", "") + "_" + version;
        ValidateTransferData result = new ValidateTransferData();
        result.setIsProxy(isProxy);
        result.setIsProduct(isProduct);

    //Get Token
        String url = "http://apibm.fr/token";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);            
    }
```

How can I add my request?

Thank you so much.

Comment: i really dont get your question , and i cannot understand what you try to achieve with the sample code. What exactly are you doing with the `StringBuffer response` ?? Anyway , if i get your issue, you want to attach the `HttpServletRequest` into the response. This cannot be done because it is not Serializable. You might need a custom wrapper to do that , check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410172/how-serialize-httpservletrequest-httpservletresponse) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900388/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-converting-httpservletrequest-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

No need to put it in paramas. Simply autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@RequestMapping(value = "/apiproxy", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity get(@RequestParam("productName") String productName,
    @RequestParam("version") String version) {

try {       
    String proxyName = productName.replaceFirst("_product", "") + "_" + version;
    ValidateTransferData result = new ValidateTransferData();
    result.setIsProxy(isProxy);
    result.setIsProduct(isProduct);

//Get Token
    String url = "http://apibm.fr/token";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);            
}
```

Then use it as you may.

Comment: Edited with full solution